# bson_finish() can be used in mongo-c-driver-1.0.2?

Tags: mongo-c-driver

I am using mongo-c-driver-1.0.2. Can I use  bson_finish()? 
I already added . But the error is error: ‘bson_finish’ was not declared in this scope.

Should I use  bson_finish()?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should using libbson instead mongo-c-driver, libbson using #include< bson.h > while mongo-c using #include< mongoc.h >

or maybe did you mean

```
bson_destroy()
```